# Maven profile parameters aren't loaded in Spring JUnit context

Tags: spring, maven, junit

I'm running JUnit tests with Maven profile.

Maven profile looks so:

```
<profile>
    <id>someProfile</id>
    <properties>
        ...
        <some.param>some_value</some.param>
        ... 
    </properties>
</profile>
```

Spring context file(*testContext.xml*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       ...
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       ...
       xsi:schemaLocation="...">
    <bean id="someBean" class="someClass"
          scope="singleton"
          autowire="byName"
          init-method="init"
          p:someBeanParam="${some.param}"/>
</beans>
```

And test class begins so:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/testContext.xml"})
@Configurable
...
```

After running maven, I saw that testContext.xml wasn't changed - *p:someBeanParam* still had value *${some.param}*.

Could you tell, please, what's the problem here and how to solve it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the directory of `testContext.xml` starting with project root?

Comment: testContext.xml is in folder 'src/test/resources', if you ask this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable resource filtering like this

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
     ...
     <resources>
         ...
         <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
         </resource>
         ...
     </resources>
     <testResources>
         ...
         <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
         </testResource>
         ...
     </testResources>
     ...
  </build>
  ....
```

Define variable for each profile and when no profile is used.

More information on [Maven Resource Plugin page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, this way didn't help, _p:someBeanParam_ didn't change its value.

Comment: What about now? Added section for test resources as you are using `testContext.xml` which should be in directory standard directory `/src/test/resources`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, now it works. Sorry, was inattentive, at first I added `<directory>src/test/resources</directory>` with tags `<resources>` and `<resource>` instead of `<testResources>` and `<testResource>`. Thanks a lot!